# Is there a way to use the new plugins without updating to Redmine 2.0?

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins, bitnami

I want to update plugins on redmine but I keep receiving this error message after updating the file:
`The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to mainenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.`

I believe that there is a compatibility problem with the new plugins and the Redmine version I am using. The plugins are made compatible with Redmine 2.0, but I am using Redmine 1.4.1.stable.

Is there a way to use the new plugins without updating to Redmine 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess we cannot. It does not work after testing 10 different plugins.